# GTMetrix ignores Jetpack CDN

Tags: wordpress, cdn, jetpack, gtmetrix

I am using Jetpack with WordPress. I'm using the new image and assets CDN service they provide, but when I test the site in GTMetrix, I score a 0 for CDN. It gives a link to add the CDN in my account if it's not recognized, but I'd rather not make an account if I don't have to. I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature which is unlocked when a user signs up with GTMetrix account.
Although that won't affect a large amount of percentage in your PageSpeed and YSlow score.
You can't reach the 100% score anyways so that can be ignored.
Try pagespeed insights by Google for more realistic results.